# Product load event - regardless of context

Tags: product, collection

Is there a single event that I can create an observer for that gets fired when a product is loaded either using `getModel` or through a collection?

The exact use case i have is that i have a custom product attribute, but in order to return the correct result, further logic needs to be done which is based on other factors?  I am then planning to compute this logic after load and store it in another member.  If someone has an alternative i would be also grateful for this advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an observer to do this. You can use the attribute `backend_model` to handle your logic.

If you specify a backend_model with your attribute and you extend the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract` class within your backend model class you can use the `afterLoad`, `beforeSave`, `afterSave`, `beforeDelete` or `afterDelete` methods to execute your own logic.

Using the `backend_model` is the correct way to implement this sort of logic and is how native Magento attributes do it where they have similiar requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it looks like you might have to use two here :(

Product: `catalog_product_load_after`
Collection: `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

The collection event gives you a 'collection' object to work with. You can loop through this and make your changes on a product level. If you move your code into a helper or use the same `Observer.php` for both events then you should be able to limit the amount of duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<catalog_product_load_after>
     <observers>
      ...
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763829/magento-load-product-event-observer

Comment: that wont work for products loaded through a collection